# Shifting the total group by 1 step- MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, window-functions

Here I have name and pay as columns of a database table.

Table has Name and Pay(sorted lowest to highest) as columns and "column I need" is the required column.

[image]

I need the rightmost column, it is displaying basically the next pay.
Gross, Stanford pay is 14, the next highest pay is 15. Likewise for others.

How can I do this?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show an expected result?

Comment: Please only tag the relevant RDBMS, and see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Please add information of calculating the rightmost column. I can't figure it out why Darson and Meads have got different values ?

Comment: Column sorted by pay.Here Darson next highest pay is 22, similarly, Meads Next highest pay is 20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you want the "next" value `pay`.

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions and a `range` frame:

```
select t.*,
    min(pay) over(order by pay range between 1 following and unbounded following) next_pay
from mytable t
```

In earlier versions, an alternative is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
    (select min(t1.pay) from mytable t1 where t1.pay > t.pay) next_pay
from mytable t
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is working if the pay is integer but when there is a decimal to it. Its showing a different number.

Comment: @RamyaM: your sample data did not show decimals. Say you have 2 decimal digits, you might want to use `over(order by pay * 100 range between 1 following and unbounded following)`. Or just use the subquery solution, that works regardless of the numeric type.